# Is this makefile example correct?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm looking at this makefile example from an academic course I'm following and some doubts emerged. Hope you will be able to clarify them.

**(1)** I'm wondering why the automatic variable $^ in the $(SRCDIR)/%.o: %.c receipe is needed? Couldn't just  `$(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)` suffice?

**(2)** Regarding the % wildcard, if I have for instance ./src/main.c, `$(SRCDIR)/%.o: %.c` will be translated to `./src/main.o : ./src/main.c` or just `./src/main.o : main.c` ? In the second case, wouldn't the resulting receipe be wrong? 
`$(CC) -c ./src/main.c $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)` VS  `$(CC) -c main.c $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)`

**(3)** Also, why is -lpthread needed? Is it something related to the makefile options or it means just that some of the files are potentially using the pthread library? I thought many of this basic libraries were already present in the basic GNU toolchain.
Thanks in advance as always.

```
NAME = myprog
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -I $(INCDIR)
LDFLAGS = -lpthread -lm
SRCDIR = ./src
INCDIR = ./include
BINDIR = /usr/local/bin
SOURCES = $(SRCDIR)/main.c $(SRCDIR)/dummy_functions.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

$(SRCDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $^ -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
...
```

Comment: `-lpthread` is typically needed, and not enabled by default by gcc

Comment: -lpthread and -lm are optional libraries so you don't need to add them unless you're using their functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes.  You should definitely *not* try to learn how to write makefiles from this course :-/.

For (1), you definitely *do not* want to use `$^` when compiling, because it will add all your header files (should you declare any or set up to autogenerate them) to the compile line which is wrong.  It should use `$<`.

For (2), you're right: the `%` is identical between the target and prerequisite, or the pattern rule doesn't match.  The pattern rule should be either `%.o : %.c` or else `$(SRCDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c`, *or else* you need to set `VPATH = $(SRCDIR)` in your makefile so make knows where to look for sources it can't find.

For (3), this is not related to make or makefiles: if your code uses threading then you need to add this option to the link line or you'll get link errors.  Technically this is obsoleted by the `-pthread` option which should appear on *both* the compile and link lines.  The compiler/linker do not add these libraries on their own you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Concise and precise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$<` expands to the first dependency. `$^` contains them all. If the target has multiple dependencies (perhaps via a separate dependency declaration somewhere else in the `Makefile`), `$<` will not contain them all.  Whether that is *incorrect*  will depend on additional circumstances, but typically I would say it is at least surprising (and if you really only want the first file, you should spell that out in a comment at least).